# Intel HAXM not working on i5-2430M (2nd Gen)

Tags: android, sdk, haxm

I was setting up HAXM for Android x86 emulator. Downloaded HAXM and x86 image using SDK manager. Installed HAXM, rebooted, still HAXM isn't shown to be working while emulator starts up.

I've tried installing HAXM directly from Intel website. Still it doesn't work.

I've enabled Virtualization from my BIOS.

System:

- HP Pavilion g6 1201-tx, Windows 7 Ultimate x64, Intel 2nd Gen i5-2430M

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try these `three` steps:

> > 1.Hax software would be located
> >         in
> >
> > `C:\Program
> >     Files\Android\android-sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`
> >
> > Install the HAXM Driver by running "IntelHaxm.exe" in command Prompt.
> >
> > 2.. if the installer fails with message that Intel VT must be turned on,
> >         you need to enable this in *BIOS*.
> >
> > ```
> > For Eg:
> > ```
> >
> > if You are using windows 7, press F12 key to enter into bios setting.
> >         There you can see the `Intel Virtualization Technology placed in System Performance`.Turn it **on** as enabled
> >
> > 3.Then again run the "IntelHaxm.exe" in command Prompt.Everything will be works fine.

Comment: As I said earlier, I've already enabled Virtualization. But HAXM doesn't display message that its running when start up emulator.

HAXM process in the Windows System is running when I checked it with command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you this HAXM Tutorial created by Intel: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture

I have the same problem but finally found my mistake. I'm using an API that doesn't support HAXM acceleration (API 19).

> Intel HAXM only works in combination with one of the Intel® Atom™
>   processor x86 system images, which are available for Android 2.3.3
>   (API 10), 4.0.3 (API 15), 4.1.2 (API 16), 4.2.2 (API 17). These Intel
>   system images can be installed exactly the same way as the ARM-based
>   images via the SDK manager.

Supported API (10,15,16,17) combined with Intel Atom (x86) on CPU/ABI is the correct combination.

Comment: My HAXM release notes says: `Intel(R) HAXM requires the Android SDK to be installed (version 17 or higher).
For best performance, using SDK version 20 or higher is recommended.`

Comment: @ScottStafford have you a link with this documentation? I want to use a higher API version. In my the most higher API version that work with HAXM is 17... I test wit 18, 19 and 20 but doesn't works acceleration.

Comment: The one I use I got via the `android` package downloader, that got put in my /plugins directory.

Comment: @ScottStafford you're right, I see it this message on Prerequisites. But in my case steel only working with API 17. If I use API 18, 19 or 20 I can't see the acceleration message when AVD is starting.