# Haxm is not installing on my system. Intel(r) core i5

Tags: android, flutter, haxm

[image]

Should I need to enable the Window hypervisor platform in my window?
I have an HP laptop and Intel (R) processor core i5.
I also enable the virtual technology (VTx) from bios.
Also disabled the Hyper V in my windows.

Comment: it will be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445368/intel-haxm-not-working-on-i5-2430m-2nd-gen#:~:text=Install%20the%20HAXM%20Driver%20by,to%20enable%20this%20in%20BIOS.&text=3.,.exe%22%20in%20command%20Prompt.

Comment: Looks like VMX is disabled. You can enable it in your BIOS.